# What is the difference between SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

How SharePoint online differ from SharePoint server 2013,

1. What are the requirements for SharePoint online?
2. How to install it?
3. Is there any way to migrate SharePoint server 2013 to SharePoint online
   ?

Please let me know your comments

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers of your questions:

- **SharePoint server 2013** is on premise version, which is installed over your compatible hardware/system. While **SharePoint Online** is built up by Microsoft also called **Office 365**. It is based on cloud so with the few limitations in programming to build any solution for it.
- **SharePoint Online** is cloud based platform. You need to buy different plans [here](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans). Once you buy any plan you will given a URL to login into the Office 365 portal and access SharePoint online sites.
- It is not installer. It is portal that you can access from the browser.
- There are lot of tools available for migrating data from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online, here is the [link](https://collab365.community/sharepoint-comparison-matrix-for-3rd-party-migration-tools/) for different tools of migration.